# Issue with NVME controller from kernel 5.18 onwards. What should I do from here?

Tags: drivers, kernel, ssd, 23.04

I have an Asus ZenBook Duo (UX481FL) but am having issues with any kernels beyond 5.18, my NVME controller will not work.

After anywhere up to 5 minutes after booting the SSD stops responding and crashes my computer, to try and diagnose the issue here is a live environment's logs. I have tried setting the kernel parameters it has suggested and it still does not work. My SSD is a `WDC PC SN520 SDAPNUW-512G-1002` according to smartctl.

```
[    5.451483] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:04:00.0
[    5.459899] nvme nvme0: 8/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[    5.462781]  nvme0n1: p1 p2 p4
[  530.755521] nvme nvme0: controller is down; will reset: CSTS=0xffffffff, PCI_STATUS=0xffff
[  530.755532] nvme nvme0: Does your device have a faulty power saving mode enabled?
[  530.755536] nvme nvme0: Try "nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0 pcie_aspm=off" and report a bug
[  530.825745] nvme 0000:04:00.0: Unable to change power state from D3cold to D0, device inaccessible
[  530.826126] nvme nvme0: Disabling device after reset failure: -19
[  530.842408] nvme0n1: detected capacity change from 1000215216 to 0
[  530.853460] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p4, logical block 1048560, async page read
[  530.853752] Buffer I/O error on dev nvme0n1p2, logical block 123846384, async page read
```

This affects all distros I have tested and have resorted to using the 5.15 LTS kernel. I also posted on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=280106 asking if they managed to resolve their issue. What should my next steps be from here? Is there any way I could further diagnose this issue? Is there anywhere else I should post this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=214035

Comment: Have you updated both UEFI firmware & SSD firmware? Not sure with your system if SSD firmware update would be from System vendor or SSD vendor. To see version your have: `udisksctl status` or install nvme-cli & `sudo nvme list`

Comment: oldfred - My UEFI firmware is up to date, I am not so sure about my SSD firmware, through the firmware app there are no updates listed for my SSD and on WD's website there is only a windows application listed which apparently updates it but I do not have a windows installed.